# Calling a webservice with CXF Spring injection

Tags: spring, web-services, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, cxf

I write again, this time regarding a problem with CXF.
My scenario: I have two tomcat 7 servers running. One has a Webservice running, it is a JAXWS with Spring from one easy example at javacodegeeks (here for reference).
The second server is a client server which hopefully will end up calling the webservice rightly with Spring injection. I copied the wsdl from the first server inside a folder, and put the wsdl2java plugin in my maven build, wich worked wonders. Then I created the cxf.xml and put it in the src/main/config folder (has suggested). Afterwards I created a simple JSF that calls my Java with a simple Manage Bean. And here the problems started:
As seen in the Apache CXF page, you only need to create a ‘client’ bean in order to call all the methods inside our webservice, although when I call it, it gives me this exception: javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Cannot find dispatch method for {}

It seems that the ‘client’ bean hasn’t got the namespace or the name of the function I am calling.
I am a little bit lost in here, since it is the first time I use CXF.
Could someone help me?

For reference, the files:
CXF.XML

```
>  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <beans
> xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
>        xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
>        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>        xsi:schemaLocation="
>           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
>           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
>           http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws
>           http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">
>  
>     <jaxws:client id="client"
>                   serviceClass="com.javacodegeeks.enterprise.ws.MyWebService"
>                   address="http://localhost:8080/JAXWS-Spring/jaxws-spring"
>                   wsdlLocation="http://localhost:8080/JAXWS-Spring/jaxws-spring?wsdl" />
> </beans>`
```

The JavaCode that I call through my Bean:

```
@Named
public class UserBoImpl implements UserBo, Serializable{


/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public String getMessage() {

    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[]{"cxf.xml"});

    MyWebService client = (MyWebService)context.getBean("client");

    String response = client.printMessage();
    System.out.println("Response: " + response);

    return response;

}
```

}

My wsdl:

> ```
> <definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
>            name="MyWebService" 
>            targetNamespace="http://ws.enterprise.javacodegeeks.com/" 
>            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
>            xmlns:tns="http://ws.enterprise.javacodegeeks.com/" 
>            xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
>            xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" 
>            xmlns:wsp1_2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" 
>            xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" 
>            xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
>
>   <types/> 
>   <message name="printMessage"/> 
>   <message name="printMessageResponse"> 
>       <part type="xsd:string" name="return"/> 
>   </message> 
>   <portType name="MyWebService"> 
>       <operation name="printMessage"> 
>           <input message="tns:printMessage" wsam:Action="http://ws.enterprise.javacodegeeks.com/MyWebService/printMessageRequest"/>
>
>           <output message="tns:printMessageResponse" wsam:Action="http://ws.enterprise.javacodegeeks.com/MyWebService/printMessageResponse"/>
>
>       </operation> 
>   </portType> 
>   <binding type="tns:MyWebService" name="MyWebServicePortBinding"> 
>       <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/> 
>       <operation name="printMessage"> <soap:operation soapAction=""/> 
>           <input> 
>               <soap:body namespace="http://ws.enterprise.javacodegeeks.com/" use="literal"/> 
>           </input> 
>           <output> 
>               <soap:body namespace="http://ws.enterprise.javacodegeeks.com/" use="literal"/> 
>           </output> 
>       </operation> 
>   </binding> 
>   <service name="MyWebService"> 
>       <port name="MyWebServicePort" binding="tns:MyWebServicePortBinding"> 
>           <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/JAXWS-Spring/jaxws-spring"/> 
>       </port> 
>   </service> 
> </definitions>
> ```

The full StackTrace:

```
    INFO: Creating Service {http://ws.enterprise.javacodegeeks.com/}MyWebServiceService from WSDL: http://localhost:8080/JAXWS-Spring/jaxws-spring?wsdl
Mar 12, 2014 5:31:09 PM com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy handleRenderException
SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/default.xhtml]
javax.el.ELException: /default.xhtml: javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Cannot find dispatch method for {}
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.TextInstruction.write(TextInstruction.java:88)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions.encodeBegin(UIInstructions.java:82)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UILeaf.encodeAll(UILeaf.java:183)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:443)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Cannot find dispatch method for {}
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:157)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy32.printMessage(Unknown Source)
    at com.saidinit.user.bo.impl.UserBoImpl.getMessage(UserBoImpl.java:26)
    at com.saidinit.common.UserBean.printMsgFromSpring(UserBean.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:476)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:161)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:172)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextVariable.writeText(ELText.java:227)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextComposite.writeText(ELText.java:150)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.TextInstruction.write(TextInstruction.java:85)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: Cannot find dispatch method for {}
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultInInterceptor.unmarshalFault(Soap11FaultInInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultInInterceptor.handleMessage(Soap11FaultInInterceptor.java:51)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultInInterceptor.handleMessage(Soap11FaultInInterceptor.java:40)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.onMessage(AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.java:113)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.CheckFaultInterceptor.handleMessage(CheckFaultInterceptor.java:69)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.CheckFaultInterceptor.handleMessage(CheckFaultInterceptor.java:34)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:835)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1614)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1504)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1310)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:628)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:565)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:474)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:377)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:330)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:135)
    ... 43 more

Mar 12, 2014 5:31:09 PM com.sun.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl log
1100: JSF1073: javax.el.ELException caught during processing of RENDER_RESPONSE 6 : UIComponent-ClientId=, Message=/default.xhtml: javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Cannot find dispatch method for {}
Mar 12, 2014 5:31:09 PM com.sun.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl log
1100: /default.xhtml: javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Cannot find dispatch method for {}
javax.el.ELException: /default.xhtml: javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Cannot find dispatch method for {}
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.TextInstruction.write(TextInstruction.java:88)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions.encodeBegin(UIInstructions.java:82)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UILeaf.encodeAll(UILeaf.java:183)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:443)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Cannot find dispatch method for {}
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:157)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy32.printMessage(Unknown Source)
    at com.saidinit.user.bo.impl.UserBoImpl.getMessage(UserBoImpl.java:26)
    at com.saidinit.common.UserBean.printMsgFromSpring(UserBean.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:476)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:161)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:172)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextVariable.writeText(ELText.java:227)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextComposite.writeText(ELText.java:150)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.TextInstruction.write(TextInstruction.java:85)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: Cannot find dispatch method for {}
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultInInterceptor.unmarshalFault(Soap11FaultInInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultInInterceptor.handleMessage(Soap11FaultInInterceptor.java:51)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultInInterceptor.handleMessage(Soap11FaultInInterceptor.java:40)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.onMessage(AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.java:113)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.CheckFaultInterceptor.handleMessage(CheckFaultInterceptor.java:69)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.CheckFaultInterceptor.handleMessage(CheckFaultInterceptor.java:34)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:835)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1614)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1504)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1310)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:628)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:565)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:474)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:377)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:330)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:135)
    ... 43 more
```

And... that's it... I think.
If you need anything more I will just edit and add it.

Hope you can help :)

Edit: corrected some fomating... 
Edit 2: added a few more tags for more visibility